# Selenium: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document' my_selector is not a valid selector

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, queryselector

When I execute:

```
document.querySelector(my_selector)
```

in selenium, it throws me an error:

```
Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document' my_selector is not a valid selector
```

`my_selector` is a valid selector that works in my local chrome browser.

```
div#some_id > div.some_class_1.some_class_2 > div#another_id > div.md:some_class
```

It contains colons, but I use double backslashes to escape them. I use `my_selector` to improve readability here because it's pretty long. Does anyone know what might be the reason?

Here is a piece of the logic:

```
function getElelement() {
  const elementPath = arguments[0]
  return document.querySelector(elementPath)
}
...
...
...
driver.executeScript(getElelement, my_selector)
```

**UPD: In the end, I moved forward with another solution. I haven't found a proper way how to solve my problem. Thanks to all of you, folks!**

Comment: What is `mySelector`?

Comment: mySelector is a valid css selector, like `div#some_id > div.some_class_1.some_class_2 > div#another_id > div.md:some_class`

Comment: You should include your html as well as how your are setting `mySelector`, so that we can have a minimal reproducible example to test.

Comment: is `some_class` a pseudo-class? Without seeing your html, it's hard to tell exactly what's going on.

Comment: You should switch to puppeteer / playwright. Otherwise you're relying on Python dummies to support your javascript code.

Answer (score -1):

Not that super clear why you would want [`executeScript()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/executeScript) which injects JavaScript code into a page where as your usecase seems just to *get an elelement*.

---

### Solution

An alternate solution would be to use just [`Document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) as follows:

```
document.querySelector("my_selector")
```

essentially:

```
document.querySelector("div#some_id > div.some_class_1.some_class_2 > div#another_id > div.md:some_class")
```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I do.

Comment: Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.